# Is there a way to trigger a breakpoint with a variable call, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am working on an existing project in Matlab/Simulink; written by a former co-worker. This project has dozens of variables and functions that are read/written and called, respectively. In an effort to understand the code a bit more, I'm trying to find when certain variables are being called during execution. Is there a way to trigger a flag when specific variables are being read/written? I was thinking it would be very helpful to trigger a breakpoint when a variable is read/written.

Comment: Variables are not called, they are read from or written to. You can search for uses of the variable name within your function, and set breakpoints on the lines found. If you are talking about global variables, you might want to stop using those exactly for this reason, it's hard to track where and when they're being modified.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately, I didn't create the code; it was passed down to me. Nevertheless, I will definitely be careful about my use of global variables. What is one way you recommend searching for the variables? Do you do this within Matlab? If not, where do you it? I ask because I tried to do this using the Windows search feature, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Within a function, you just search with the editor. Actually the MATLAB Editor helps a lot by highlighting all occurrences of the variable name your cursor is on. With global variables it's harder, which is why they shouldn't be used. On Linux or MacOS you can use the command line utility `grep`. I don't know a good solution on Windows, haven't used that in >10 years now.

Comment: Here are some ideas you could try: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/390061-enter-debug-mode-if-a-variable-changes-value